# application does not search a random-access file for zero

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

```
class Screen extends JFrame {
    private RandomAccessFile raf;
    private JTextField tfReqSSN;

    public Screen() throws IOException {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("stuff.dat", "r");
        tfReqSSN.addActionListener(new HandlerSSN());
    }

    private class HandlerSSN implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int ssn = 0;
            String ssnReqStr = tfReqSSN.getText();//enter text to SSN field

            if (ssnReqStr.length() != 9) {
                clearReqFields(); //clears input fields
                tfMsg.setText("Invalid SSN Length.");
            } else {
                // validate request
                if (isNumeric(ssnReqStr)) { //isNumeric is a method that checks if the string is a number
                    raf.seek(0);
                    while (Integer.parseInt(ssnReqStr) != ssn
                            && raf.getFilePointer() < raf.length()) {
                         read lines.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, when "000000000" is entered for the SSN it doesn't do a search at all, it just returns whatever the initial values are, i.e. 0 or null. From what I can tell it is not reading the entry as the number zero, it is reading it as nothing. Is this a thing with integers? Should I instead change ssn to a string to compare?

I apologize if this isn't enough code, the application is pretty big so I just wanted to give you guys only what is needed.

Comment: No, you did the right thing by providing a short 'n' sweet example that shows the issue. Better yet would be _just_ the code to read and parse the file in a [small, compileable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Better still would be if making that snippet showed you your problem; then you can post it as an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
int ssn = 0;
...
while (Integer.parseInt(ssnReqStr) != ssn
```

Since ssnReqStr equals "000000000" it is parsed to 0, and the value of ssn is also set to 0, which means that the while loop doesn't even execute once since the condition is already met.

I am assuming that the ssn is being read inside the while loop. If the input number cannot be negative, you could try setting the initial value of ssn to -1. That way it will always have to be executed at least once. Or you could convert the while loop to a do-while, so the initial value doesn't even matter.

P.S. if the length of the file is large, it might be more efficient to parse the input number before doing the search.